# concatenate xarray.DataArray and add new dimension

Tags: loops, dictionary, output, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a dictionary with 1000 keys and each key has 23 entries, each is an xarray.DataArray.
Each entry looks like this:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 23)>
array(['1861-01-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1861-02-15T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1861-03-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1861-04-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1861-05-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1861-06-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1861-07-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1861-08-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '1861-09-16T00:00:00.000000000', '1861-10-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '1861-11-16T00:00:00.000000000', '1861-12-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-01-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1862-02-15T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-03-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1862-04-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-05-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1862-06-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-07-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1862-08-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-09-16T00:00:00.000000000', '1862-10-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-11-16T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1861-02-15 ... 1862-12-16T12:00:00
    month    (time) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

I am trying to concatenate all these entries and get a new variable with dimensions ( 1000,23)

which would look like

<xarray.DataArray 'entries','time' (entries:1000,time: 23)>

and then I want to be able to write this into a Netcdf file so to use .to_netcdf.

If I do

```
tt=xr.concat(entry[0],entry[1])
```

I get the following:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 23)>
array(['1861-01-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1861-02-15T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1861-03-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1861-04-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1861-05-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1861-06-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1861-07-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1861-08-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '1861-09-16T00:00:00.000000000', '1861-10-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '1861-11-16T00:00:00.000000000', '1861-12-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-01-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1862-02-15T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-03-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1862-04-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-05-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1862-06-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-07-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1862-08-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-09-16T00:00:00.000000000', '1862-10-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-11-16T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1861-01-16T12:00:00 1861-02-15 ... 1862-11-16
    month    (time) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 23)>
array(['1861-01-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1861-02-15T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1861-03-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1861-04-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1861-05-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1861-06-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1861-07-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1861-08-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '1861-09-16T00:00:00.000000000', '1861-10-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '1861-11-16T00:00:00.000000000', '1861-12-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-01-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1862-02-15T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-03-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1862-04-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-05-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1862-06-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-07-16T12:00:00.000000000', '1862-08-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-09-16T00:00:00.000000000', '1862-10-16T12:00:00.000000000',
       '1862-11-16T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1861-02-15 ... 1862-12-16T12:00:00
    month    (time) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

So how I loop over this and transform the entries of the dictionary into a new dimension for the xarran.DataArray and get the (1000,23) xarray.DataArray ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

```
ds = xr.Dataset({'Entry_0': entry[0], 
'Entry_1': entry[1], 
'Entry_2': entry[2]
#... and so on
})
```

Or another way to do the same thing is:

```
# create empty xarray dataset
ds = xr.Dataset({})
# add data arrays to xarray dataset
ds['Entry_0'] = entry[0]
ds['Entry_1'] = entry[1]
ds['Entry_2'] = entry[2]
# add so on
```

Or use a for loop for more concise code:

```
# create empty list to store xarray data arrays
data_arrays = []
# for loop to add data arrays to list
for idx in range(len(entry)): 
    da = entry[idx]
    data_arrays.append(da)
# concatenate list of data arrays along new dimension into xarray dataset
ds = xarray.concat(data_arrays, dim='new_dim')
```